# Should I nest these classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, nested

I have two classes. When I first started, it logically made sense for me to nest them because they are directly associated with one another:

```
class ClassA
{
    List<ClassB> list = new ArrayList();

    public boolean add(ClassB cB)
    {
        return list.add(cB);
    }

    public ClassB get(int index)
    {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    class ClassB
    {
        public int test()
        {
            return 123;
        }
    }
}
```

As I progressed, I began to wonder if it would be better not to nest them. If I wanted to add a constructor to ClassA, such as:

```
public ClassA(List<ClassB> list)
```

it would create difficulty. In order to create the list to pass to the constructor, it would require me to have an instance of ClassA that I might not have at the time, which would defeat the purpose of having such a constructor in the first place.

Logically, I will only ever use ClassB in association with ClassA, but I might need to reference ClassB directly, without having an instance of ClassA to do so. Should I nest these classes, or separate them?

Comment: You can review the documentation from the java team - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html - that will provide you some direction.

Comment: @BobLukens Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be referencing to ClassB while an instance of ClassA is not available, then do not nest ClassB.

If it were to be nested then you would need an object ClassA to access ClassB as it can only exist within an instance of ClassA.